# Token Authentication with web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

My scenario is that we're using MongoDB as a storage backend, and on the client side we use DustJS/bootstrap and jquery plugins for the rest. No complex client side frameworks. It's a single page app and when the user has entered a user/pass in the login form, we create a token based on the user and password, store some info about the user in it (firstname, lastname and so on), expiry date, and the sign the token. This is like max 5-10 lines of code. 
When the user logs out, we invalidate the token.

Then we auth the user from the token after this, this is all done in an actionfilter.

This takes me(you) 5 minutes to create.

I've been reading through dozens of tutorials and posts about asp.net identity, jwt bearer tokens, cookie middleware and so on. I've also looked through the sample project when you start a new project with Windows Authentcation in asp.net mvc api.

It really baffles me on how much complexity and code is needed to get this working.

So if anyone can enlighten me, why can't I just use my simple approach and still be as safe as the complex approach? If you have a reason, please specify exactly why, don't just say XSS and CSRF, those are easily avoided.